# How to compute the Liapunov exponents in henon map?

Tags: chaos-theory

I am trying to compute the Liapunov exponents in [Henón map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map), but i don't know the theory that i need, in logistic map is easy but in 2-dimensions?
how is in general case? i need program it in Fortran 90.
(i don't write english very well, so excuse me).

Comment: You can use Wolf algorithm to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate your difficulties? In particular how do you calculate the Lyapunov exponent for the logistic map and which aspects do you fail to translate to two dimensions? Without these details, we can only point you to general algorithms like the above comment did, but as you seem to already know them, this will probably not help you.

Comment: ok, i use :  lambda=lim n-->∞   {(1/n)  Σ ln |f ' (xi)| } in logistic map and so i can compute exactly the exponents. But henon map is two dimensional, i read that i need Jacobian matrix but i can´t calculate.

Comment: then, Which theory need i to learn? Parameters values: a=1.75    and    b=0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you just need to do the same thing in two dimensions that you did in one dimension for the.

Now if

$$x_{n+1} = f_1(x_n, y_n)$$
$$y_{n+1} = f_2(x_n, y_n)$$

you need to find functions for

$$ln |{\partial f_1 \over \partial x}|$$
$$ln |{\partial f_1 \over \partial y}|$$
$$ln |{\partial f_2 \over \partial x}|$$
$$ln |{\partial f_2 \over \partial y}|$$

so first you do lots of iterations to find $x_{1000}$ and $y_{1000}$, for example.

Then you do lots more iterations to find the average values of the four functions $ln |{\partial f_1.....}$ --- these four averages are the four matrix elements of the Jacobean matrix [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

I expect the determinant of this matix is similar to the one dimensional Lyapunov constant.